# Указанный аргумент находился вне диапазона

Tags: c#, windows-7, сокет, windows-server

Я новичек в C#, поэтому я не знаю почеум на Windows 7 мое приложение работает отлично, а на Windows Server 2012 у меня ошибка, когда я пытаюсь получить сообщение с клиента. Пишу программу в Visual Studio 2013.

**Ошибка** (Windows Server):

> system.argumentOutOfRangeException:
> Specified argument was out of the
> range of valid values. Parameter name:
> Size. at
> system.net.sockets.networkStream.Read(Byte[]
> buffer, int32 offset, int32 size)

Функция отправки:

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

Функция получения сообщения:

```
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
```

Проблема явно в строке:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Размерность clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize стандартная, не менялась.

byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];

**(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize** Windows Server говорит что тут я превышаю какой-то размер, какой я понять не могу, ведь в Windows 7 все работает. В общем вопрос в том, как её исправить?

Comment: @Владимир Желнов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

> Проблема явно в строке:
>
> `networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);`

Я бы поспорил.

Согласно [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) параметр `size` - это "Число байтов, запрашиваемых из объекта NetworkStream.". А сама функция возвращает "Число байтов, прочитанных из объекта NetworkStream.". И, на сколько я помню, не факт что вы получите столько сколько попросили.

А ошибка у вас, скорее всего, появляется на строчке

`dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));`

т.к. в строке `dataFromClient` нет символа "$" и Ваш вызов по сути сводится к

`dataFromClient.Substring(0, -1);`

Что, собственно, и приводит к `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Чтобы этого не было, Вам необходимо дополучить все данные. Для этого можно, например, перед отправкой самих данных отправлять размер этих данных, а потом вызывать `Read` пока не получите все данные

Comment: Можете объяснить или привести пример указания размера перед отправкой?

Comment: @Владимир Желнов, просто перед самими данными, добавляете их размер.

Например, надо отправить строку "TEST" (будем счиать, что по байту на букву). Тогда в итоге отправляете 4TEST. Четвёрку, естественно, отправляете как число, например `int`.